# How to show the selected values from database and show in multiple select box in php

Tags: php, html-select

i have a array like

`$a = array("A", "B", "C");`

i have stored the values in database using multiple select.

saved values are `"B", "C"` in 2 different rows

I need to show the selected value `"b"` and `"D"` value in to the same multiple select box.

here the tough concept is i need to display the value of select option from the array as follows

```
   foreach($dbRows as $dbRow) {
       // here if i display the selected values using if condition the value are selected by the array values repeats like
        a - no selected
        b - selected
        c - no selected

again loops repeats like

       a - no selected
       b - no selected
       c - selected

   }
}
```

how to display the values in a without repeat?

Comment: Please update your question by changing the tags. Missing javascript in your code.

Comment: Basic check with `in_array`. I also hope the values stored in DB are not comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the select box array and check if it's value is in DB array using [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$a = array("A", "B", "C");

foreach($a as $v)
{
    $selected = in_array($v, $db_array) ? 'selected' : '';
}
```

Comment: Not up to results. Expecting little more but, its useful.

Comment: Thanks Aravindan. We at SO are here to fix the problem, and not to code completely for you. This is how you learn.

Comment: What i expect is a clue to work for that that is it.